# (Processing) GROUP PShape getWidth() or width is 0.0

Tags: processing

I want to get the width and the height of a GROUP PShape, but I only get 0.0.

For example:

```
// Example code from "https://processing.org/reference/PShape_addChild_.html"

PShape house;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);

  // Make a group PShape
  house = createShape(GROUP);
  
  // Make three shapes
  PShape path = createShape();
  path.beginShape();
  path.vertex(-20, -20);
  path.vertex(0, -40);
  path.vertex(20, -20);
  path.endShape();
  PShape rectangle = createShape(RECT, -20, -20, 40, 40);
  PShape circle = createShape(ELLIPSE, 0, 0, 20, 20);
  
  // Add all three as children
  house.addChild(path);
  house.addChild(rectangle);
  house.addChild(circle);
  
  println(house.width, house.getWidth());
  println(house.height, house.getHeight());
}

void draw() {
  background(52);
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  shape(house);
}
```

In this code, `println(house.width, house.getWidth());` and `println(house.height, house.getHeight());` show `0.0 0.0`

So, how can I get the width and the height of any PShape?

---

**Edit**

Following the advice from @Rabbid76, I have created a getBoundingBoxLimits() function:

```
float[][] getBoundingBoxLimits(PShape s){
  float[][] coords = {{1000000.0, -1000000.0}, {1000000.0, -1000000.0}}; 
  // coords represents {{min_x, max_x}, {min_y, max_y}}
  float ii, jj;
  
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    for(int j=0; i<1000; j++){
      ii = i*1.0;
      jj = j*1.0;
      if(s.contains(ii,jj)){ // contains() expects floats, not ints
        if(ii < coords[0][0]) { coords[0][0] = ii; }
        if(ii > coords[0][1]) { coords[0][1] = ii; }
        if(jj < coords[1][0]) { coords[1][0] = jj; }
        if(jj > coords[1][1]) { coords[1][1] = jj; }         
       }
    }
  }

  return coords;
}
```

But it returns an `IllegalArgumentException: The contains() method is only implemented for paths.`.

So, at first glance, it seems that I cannot determine if a (x, y) point is in any PShape other than a PATH PShape.

Anyway, I am expecting a more straightforward way of getting the width and the height of any PShape (as I am sure this information is stored inside any of these objects).

Comment: Related: [Bounding box of an arbitrary shape?](https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/bounding-box-of-an-arbitrary-shape.html)